# Настройка RDP в Windows через коммандную строку

Tags: cmd, windows-7, rdp

[image: RDP]Случилась ситуация, настроил доступ по РДП из Linux в Window, пытаюсь залогинится, успех, но после выдает сообщение "Есть другой пользователь выполнивщий вход в систему...". Вопрос: как можно через command line (так как ТОЛЬКО к ней есть доступ) выпольнить настройку многопользовательского доступа по RDP?

Comment: А вы уверены что windows 7 поддерживает такое?

Comment: Загрузил скриншот

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что не-серверная версия windows не поддерживает больше 1 пользователя по RDP.

Comment: Возможны ли варианты обхода или установка доп. ПО можер решить эту задачу?

Comment: Это ограничение зашито где-то внутри виндовс. Не знаю есть ли варианты обхода или ПО, но если есть, там всё будет сложно

Comment: Несерверные версии Windows имеют ограничение по количеству сессий одновременно работающих пользователей - конкретно, 1. Конечно же, есть даже коммерческие решения для расширения функционала несерверных Windows ОС до многопользовательского RDP-режима. Например, **Thinstuff XP/VS Terminal Server for Windows**. Ищите и найдете. Не сможете найти, можете приобрести серверный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Есть проект, позволяющий работать нескольким пользователям одновременно: 
[RDP Wrapper Library](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap).