# Два рабочих стола в Windows 10

Tags: windows

Есть программы чтобы использовать два рабочих стола на Windows независимо друг от друга? Не засплитить окна, а именно два рабочих стола. Виртуалку ставить не хочу, ибо итак одна запущена. Суть в том что хочу использовать один рабочий стол удалённо (anydesk, tw), и в это же время (например) за компом кто то другой занимается своими делами.

Comment: Кажется это не рабочим столом называется...

Comment: Винда не в серверном исполнении позволяет работать одномоментно только одному пользователю.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/990501/191416 ?